# Creating a base class for Windows Services

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, base-class

In our application, we have a number of Windows Services (more than 30) that must run behind the scenes to process data at given times throughout the day. I was attempting to create a BaseService class that I could inherit from that would log to our database when the service started or stopped as well as some other common functionality. However, I ran into a show stopper in trying to create BaseService as MustInherit as we have a number of MustOverride properties. The issue lies in:

```
<MTAThread()> Shared Sub Main()
```

Our code is all in VB (as you can probably tell). Given that it is a Shared method, I cannot have it be overridden (i.e. make it MustOverride). Without this method, the code will not compile, however it will not really work in the base class. The code in this method is:

```
Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
 ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New BaseService}
 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
```

The BaseService (the name of my base class) cannot be created because it is specified as MustInherit. And therein lies my problem. I cannot create this in the Base Class and cannot override it in the inheriting classes.

Comment: Main is a method of an application, not of a service, as one application can host several services. You can separate application and service into different classes, that may make your task easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we solved this exact problem: we pass the implementing type to a shared `MainBase` in the base service class, then call this from the implementing class.

Here is the code from the base service class:

```
' The main entry point for the process
<MTAThread()> _
Shared Sub MainBase(ByVal ImplementingType As System.Type)
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    If InStr(Environment.CommandLine, "StartAsProcess", CompareMethod.Text) <> 0 Then
        DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(ImplementingType), ServerMonitorServiceBase).OnStart(Nothing)
    Else
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(ImplementingType), ServiceBase)}
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End If

End Sub
```

And here is the code from the implementing class:

```
' The main entry point for the process. The main method can't be inherited, so 
' implement this workaround
<MTAThread(), LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain)> _
Shared Sub Main()

    Call MainBase(GetType(ThisImplementedService))
End Sub
```